# Unknown column in field list - After MySQL changes

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework-6, mysql-connector

I have a query which pulls some data after making a couple of joins, this worked fine when the application used SQL Server. However after making the transfer to MySQL I'm having some issues.

For example I keep getting the error 'Unknown column Extent.Group_ClientID'. I have identified the line at which this error occurs at but I don't understand why.

Entity:

```
[Table("tblsupplier")]
    public partial class Supplier
    {
        [Key][Column(Order = 0)]
        public int ClientID { get; set; }

        [Key][Column(Order = 1)]
        public int SupplierID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string AccountNo { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string SupplierName { get; set; }

        public string DisplayName {
            get {
                return this.SupplierName + " (" + this.AccountNo + ")";
            }
        }

        public virtual Client tblClient { get; set; }
    }
```

Query:

```
 public IQueryable<Supplier> GetAllSuppliersByClientWithClaims(int ClientID, List<int> WrittenOffIDs) {
            return (from s in alliance.Suppliers
                    where s.ClientID == ClientID
                    join h in alliance.Headers
                    on new { a = s.ClientID, b = s.SupplierID }
                    equals new { a = h.ClientID, b = h.SupplierID }

                    join d in alliance.Details
                    on new { h.ClientID, h.ClaimID }
                    equals new { d.ClientID, d.ClaimID }

                    join r in alliance.Reviews
                    on new { h.ClientID, h.ReviewID }
                    equals new { r.ClientID, r.ReviewID }
                    where r.ReviewPeriodID != 0
                    where d.SplitLine == false
                    where !WrittenOffIDs.Contains((int)d.WrittenOffID)



 select s).Distinct().OrderBy(r => r.SupplierName);
    }
```

Method:

```
public string GetSupplierAutoComplete(int ClientID) {
            DashboardViewModel model = new DashboardViewModel();
            GeneralMethods GeneralHelpers = new GeneralMethods(reviewPeriodRepo, supplierGroupRepo, detailRepo);

            model.Suppliers = supplierRepo.GetAllSuppliersByClientWithClaims(ClientID, GeneralHelpers.GetWrittenOffCodes(ClientID));

           //Fails here
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.Suppliers.Select(r => r.DisplayName), Formatting.Indented);
            }
```

However, I have done some playing around and I've found that one of the where's in the query is causing this issue.  `where d.SplitLine == false`. Now in the database SplitLine is a Tinyint. As suggested because this is the boolean type for MySQL. Now if I pull a single 'SplitLine', it will return true or false based on the 0 or 1. Whereas if I use it in a where statement, it fails. Why it this?

UPDATE:

This only seems to happen when I enumerate the list

Comment: you sure the syntax you are using for `where` is correct? Id be expecting to see `&&` or `||` operators between the values, not additional `where`'s

Comment: @Takarii Positive, it's exactly the same code and this used to work before

Comment: are you using any external packages? LINQ doesnt nativly support MySQL if i recall correctly.

Comment: Correct, I've downloaded the MySQL Net connector package as well as MySQL to EF6 package. Other queries work, this one hasn't so far. Actually now you mention it, it cannot be that line which I've said it's failing upon as I've used the same line somewhere else so it must be something else. I'll figure it out and post the answer

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! I'm not entirely sure why the error was occurring! Anyway..

I have two entities:

Header and Group.

I have a foreign key in my header entity which create a link with group. It said that one header can have one group. Which after I reviewed, was incorrect. One header can have many groups. So I changed the foreign key from this:

```
public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
```

To:

```
public ICollection<Group> Groups {get; set; }
```

This then worked. However, I haven't made a reference to group so I'm not sure to why this threw an error. If anyone knows, please let me know in the comments.